# How to create variables local to with statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to create temporary variables visible in a limited scope.
It seems likely to me that you can do this with a "with" statement, and I would think there is a construct that makes it easy to do, but I cannot seem to find it.

I would like something like the following (but it does not work this way of course):

```
pronunciation = "E_0 g z @_1 m p l"
# ...
with pronunciation.split() as phonemes:
    if len(phonemes) > 2 or phonemes[0].startswith('E'):
        condition = 1
    elif len(phonemes) < 3 and phonemes[-1] == '9r':
        condition = 2
```

So is there a simple way to make this work, using built-ins?

Thanks!

Comment: The with builtin doesnt work that way. Why cant you do phonemes = pronounciation.split() and then if you really need to do del phonemes at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python creates local variables with function scope (once a name is used it stays alive until the end of the function).

If you really want to limit scope then "del <var>" when you want it explicitly discarded, or create separate function to act as a container for a more limited scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method

```
def process_pronunciation(pronunciation):
    phonemes = pronunciation.split()
    if len(phonemes) > 2 or phonemes[0].startswith('E'):
        condition = 1
    elif len(phonemes) < 3 and phonemes[-1] == '9r':
        condition = 2
    return condition
```

When you call the method, the local variable `phonemes` won't be available in the global namespace.

```
pronunciation = "E_0 g z @_1 m p l"
condition = process_phonemes(pronunciation)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `with`, but I don't think it's worth the trouble. Basically (in a python function) you have two scopes - global or local, that's it. If you want a symbol to have a lifespan shorter than the function you'll have to delete it afterwards using `del`. You could define your own context manager to make this happen:

```
class TempVar:
     def __init__(self, loc, name, val):
          self.loc = loc
          self.name = name
          self.val

     def __enter__(self):
          if self.name in self.loc:
              self.old = self.loc[self.name]
          self.loc[self.name] = self.val

     def __exit__(self, *exc):
          if hasattr(self, "old"):
              self.loc[self.name] = self.old
          else:
              del self.loc[self.name]
```

then you can use it to get a temporary variable:

```
with TempVar(locals(), "tempVar", 42):
    print(tempVar)
```

The working is that it modifies the `dict` containing local variables (which is supplied to the constructor via `locals()`) on entry and restoring it when leaving. Please note that this relies on that modifying the result returned by `locals()` actually modifies the local namespace - the specification does NOT guarantee this behaviour.

Another (and safer) alternative that was pointed out is that you could define a separate function which would have it's own scope. Remember it's perfectly legal to nest functions. For example:

```
def outer():
    def inner(tempVar):
         # here tempVar is in scope
         print(tempVar)

    inner(tempVar = 42)

    # here tempVar is out of scope
```

Answer (score 0):

`with` statement does not have its own scope , it uses the surrounding scope (like if the with statement is directly inside the script , and not within any function, it uses global namespace , if the `with` statement is used inside a function, it uses the function's namespace(scope)).

If you want the statements inside a with block to run in its own local scope, one possible way would be to move the logic to a function , that way the logic would be running in its own scope (and not the surrounding scope of `with`.

Example -

```
def function_for_with(f):
    #Do something.

with pronunciation.split() as phonemes:
    function_for_with(phonemes)
```

Please note, the above will not stop `phonemes` from being defined in the surrounding scope.

---

If you want that as well (move the `phonemes` into its own scope), you can move the complete with statement inside a function. Example -

```
def function_with(pronunciation):
    with pronunciation.split() as phonemes:
        #do stuff

pronunciation = "E_0 g z @_1 m p l"
function_with(pronunciation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @skyking's answer, here's an even more magical implementation of the same idea that reads almost exactly like you wrote. Introducing: **the `with var` statement**!<sup>1</sup>

```
class var:
    def __init__(self, value):
        import inspect
        self.scope = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
        self.old_vars = set(self.scope.keys())
        self.value = value
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.value
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        for name in set(self.scope.keys()) - self.old_vars:
            del self.scope[name]

### Usage:

line = 'a b c'
with var (line.split()) as words:
    # Prints "['a', 'b', 'c']"
    print(words)

# Causes a NameError
print(words)
```

It does all the nasty extracting of local variables and names for you! How swell. If you space it quirkily like I did and hide the definition in a `from boring_stuff import *` statement, you can even pretend `var` is a keyword to all of your confused co-workers.

<sup>[1] If you actually use this, the ghost of a dead parrot will probably haunt you forever. The other answers provide much saner solutions; this one is more of a joke.</sup>